# Visual studio unable to detect Sitecore.Web namespace

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore7

Currently I'm playing with sitecore 7. I followed [this blog](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/09/Create-a-Visual-Studio-2010-Project-for-a-Sitecore-Solution.aspx) to setup my visual studio with the sitecore.

Everything is fine until when I tried to create a `sc:placeholder` on the `aspx`.
It throws this error regardless whatever sitecore control I have tried to insert:

```
Error   180 The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc Sc7\Website\layouts\Customized\MainLayout.aspx.designer.cs
```

I tried to create a placeholder using code behind, no error was thrown.

---

I have tried to create an empty web application project. And added a reference to only Sitecore.Kernel.dll
I created a dummy page to test out the reference to the dll thing.
It still throws the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know the blog mentions it, but have you added a reference to the "Sitecore.Kernel" DLL in your project?  Open your references folder and ensure that there is not a problem with the reference.

Comment: Im sure about the sitecore.kernel.dll is in the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project is using .net 4.5 (you will need to use something other than VS2010)

Answer (score 0):

After default sitecore installtion Sitecore.Kernel assembly is placed in bin folder. Maybe you used 'Clean project' and after this operation your assembly was deleted. Please check if this assembly is present in bin folder. It should be loaded by IIS automatically from bin folder, even if you have wrong reference in you csproj file.

When I start new project I always move dlls from bin folder to other folder, and put references to this files in csproj, so when I run clean project (or clean solution from VS) i have empty folder (only one file is present - *.lic file).

Comment: Can you give me more in detail about how you do? maybe step by step?